# Display Active Directory Group in a MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, view, active-directory-group

I Am trying to display active directory group member in the view. When i run the Code I am having the error "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.String[]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[SSSFT.LogIT.Models.ActiveDirectory]'". Debbuging the code show all the group member i am looking for

Model Class

```
public class ActiveDirectory
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    //public string Username { get; set; }

    //public string Email { get; set; }

    public string SamAccountName { get; set; }


}
```

Controller

```
   public ActionResult Index(string username)
    {
        username = "sssftappdev";
        string[]output = null;     
        using (var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
        using (var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, username))
        {
            if (user != null)
            {
                output = user.GetGroups() //this returns a collection of principal objects
                    .Select(x => x.SamAccountName) // select the name.  you may change this to choose the display name or whatever you want
                    .ToArray(); // convert to string array
            }

        }
       return View(output);
    }
```

View

```
@model IEnumerable<SSSFT.LogIT.Models.ActiveDirectory>
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SamAccountName)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

 @foreach (var item in Model) {
  <tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SamAccountName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.id })
    </td>
   </tr>
 }

  </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this error by simply updating your @model with:

```
@model String[]
```

You are currently passing a `String[]` to your view while expecting an IEnumerable of `SSSFT.LogIT.Models.ActiveDirectory`. Either update your code to return the right type of data, or adapt your strongly typed view with the actual result you return.

Comment: Sakuto Thanks for your reply please how can i change code to return the right data type. I tried to change IEnumerable to String[] in the view that did not work